# Check if type of a dictionary is nested or not in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

Not sure if this doable or not, but was wondering if it is possible to check if a dict type is nested or not?

```
>>> nested_dict = { 'dictA': {'key_1': 'value_1'},
                 'dictB': {'key_2': 'value_2'}}
>>> print(type(nested_dict))
<class 'dict'>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to check if *any of the values inside `nested_dict` is a dictionary*?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `[type(v) for k,v in nested_dict.items()]`?

Comment: No, the values contained by the dictionary don't change its type.

Comment: Why do you need to know? This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: The answers you're getting handle dicts that directly contain dicts.  Do you need to handle indirect containment - a dict containing a list containing a dict, for example?  That's somewhat more complicated.

Answer (score 4):

Check the type of the values inside the dictionary:

```
nested_dict = { 'dictA': {'key_1': 'value_1'},
                 'dictB': {'key_2': 'value_2'}}
not_nested_dict = {'a': 'b'}


def is_nested(d):
    return isinstance(d, dict) and any(isinstance(val, dict) for val in d.values())


print(is_nested(nested_dict))
print(is_nested(not_nested_dict))
```

Returns:

```
True
False
```

Comment: Might change to: `return isinstance(d, dict) and any(isinstance(val, dict) for val in d.values())` to guard against say a list as input.

Answer (score 1):

There are no distinct types for "flat" dictionaries and "nested" dictionaries.

So you need to test

1. if `nested_dict` is a dictionary (you've already done that)
2. if `nested_dict` *contains* any dictionaries.

To test if something has a given type, it is usually preferred to use `isinstance` instead of comparing the return value of `type()` (See: [What are the differences between type() and isinstance()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance)).

So 1. would be done by

```
isinstance(nested_dict, dict)
```

You can do 2. with a loop:

```
contains_dict = False
for v in nested_dict.values():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        contains_dict = True
        break
```

or, equivalently and more simply by using the `any` function:

```
contains_dict = any(isinstance(v, dict) for v in nested_dict.values())
```